# Relations in a finitely complete category with images

Tags: category-theory, definition, relations

I can't use tikz inside MathStackExchange; so my question is on an image below.
[image]

Comment: Right after introducing this notion of composition, Freyd and Scedrov remark (p. 79) that if $T_1'$ is contained in $T_1$, then $T_{12}'$ is contained in $T_{12}$. Now, $T$ and $T'$ tabulate the same pair if and only if they are each contained in each other, so the result you're looking for follows easily from this remark. Are you having trouble proving the remark?

Comment: Hi tcamps! Thanks for your answer. I'm having trouble with proving the first statement (I thought it should be easy) you mentioned: if $T'_1$ is contained in $T_1$, then $T'_{12}$ is contained in $T_{12}$.